# Overflow:hidden messing with margins in Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, margin

I have set up some divs for my layout, a main div and a menu div.

They look perfect in Firefox, but for some reason, Chrome and Safari get messed up.

For some reason the width of the div gets smaller when `overflow:hidden;` is added to the CSS. I need `overflow:hidden;` though, because I have other floats inside the main div. You can see the example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kR7rs/2/

It shows up fine in Firefox, but in Safari and Chrome, there's a margin on the right side of the div as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the margin from `main` seems to fix it:

http://jsfiddle.net/kR7rs/3/

What I think it happening is that when `overflow:hidden` is set, the entire element wraps around the floats instead of the text within the div.  So this gives the result in the fiddle.  Then if you set a margin on it also, the width is decreased further by the left padding.

Kind of seems like a bug.

(Don't have FF right now to test it and see if it breaks it for FF.)

Comment: So overflow:hidden basically makes a block element squeeze as wide as it can without overflowing to any floats on the same line? Your solution seems to be working.. it just seems so odd to have a div on the same line as a float without any margin

Comment: I don't think i realized that would do that, but it appears to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Move `overflow:hidden` to `#wrapper`. That fixes it, but doesn't explain why.

Comment: I want to make sure my main div wraps around the floats inside it, though. That's why I put the `overflow:hidden` in there